# BASH If [[ "$a" == *"$b"* ]] Always true even when it shouldn't be

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a small bash script to monitor the output of RiotShield (a 3rd party player scraper for League of Legends) for crashes. If a keyword is found in the log it should kill the process and restart it.

Here is my bash script as is:

```
#!/bin/bash
crash[1]="disconnected"
crash[2]="38290209"
while true; do
    list=$(tail log.log)
    #clear
    echo "Reading Log"
    echo "========================================"
    echo $list
    for item in ${list//\\n/ }
    do
            for index in 1 2
            do
                    c=${crash[index]}
                    #echo "Crash Word:" $c
                    if [[ "$c" == *"$item"* ]]; then
                            echo "RiotShield has crashed."
                            echo "Killing RiotShield."
                            kill $(ps aux | grep '[R]iotShield.exe' | awk '{print $2}')
                            echo "RiotShield killed!"
                            echo "Clearing log."
                            echo > log.log
                            echo "Starting RiotShield"
                            (mono RiotShield.exe >> log.log &)

                    fi
            done

    done

    sleep 10
done
```

My crash array are keywords that I know show in the log when it crashes. I have 38290209 in there only for testing purposes as it is my summoner ID on League of Legends and the moment I preform a search for my Summoner name the ID shows in the log.

The problem is even when disconnected and 38290209 do not show up in the log my

```
if [[ "$c" == *"$item"* ]]; then
```

fires, kills the RiotShield process and then relaunches it.

The length of the crash array will grow as I find more keywords for crashes so I cant just do

```
if [[ "$c" == "*disconnected*" ]]; then
```

Please and thanks SOF

EDIT:

Adding working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
crash[1]="disconnected"
crash[2]="error"
while true; do
    list=$(tail log.log)
    clear
    echo "Reading Log"
    echo "========================================"
    echo $list
    for index in 1 2
    do
            c=${crash[index]}
            #echo "Crash Word:" $c
            if [[ $list == *$c* ]]; then
                    echo "RiotShield has crashed."
                    echo "Crash Flag: " $c
                    echo "Killing RiotShield."
                    kill $(ps aux | grep '[R]iotShield.exe' | awk '{print $2}')
                    echo "RiotShield killed!"
                    echo "Clearing log."
                    echo > log.log
                    echo "Starting RiotShield"
                    (mono RiotShield.exe >> log.log &)
                    fi
            done
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Bash can be a tricksy beast, fwiw, I would recommend Python for such scripting tasks.

Comment: I started with python, but since I never took the time to do much with it I quickly gave up and went to bash.

Comment: I used to script everything in Bash but once I discovered Python I found it a much more transparent language. Bash has too many 'gotchas' for my liking.

Comment: An unrelated item, but you should not use a sleeping while loop with tail and a for loop. This can miss items, and makes your system far busier than necessary. [I've created a gist](https://gist.github.com/4708226) showing how to do this.

Comment: I like your gist, it's nice and clean. However I am seeing $item when it is not declared. Also not sure how you are able to compare the tail against the crash array. I guess I don't understand the --follow=name parameter either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have the operands in your expression the wrong way around. It should be:

```
if [[ $item == *$c* ]]; then
```

because you want to see if a keyword (`$c`) is present in the line (`$item`).

Also, I'm not sure why you need to break the line into items by doing this: `${list//\\n/ }`. You can just match the whole line.

Also note that double-quotes are not required within `[[`.

Comment: I eliminated the ${list//\\n/ } per your suggestions and I swapped out $item for $list and changed its location with $c and it seems like it wants to work. Thanks!